# Generate deployment for project with existing infrastructure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to incorporate Deployment Manager into my project which already has various instances of services up and running. I don't want to write deployments for all of them, and was hoping GCP offered a tool to generate them automatically, since it has exact information about which infrastructure components are up and how they are configured. Does such a tool exist?

Comment: If you use terraform (and I (and Google also) recommend to use Terraform instead of deployment manager), you have [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) that help you in this task.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks a lot, that tool looks great! Do you remember where you saw Google recommend Terraform?

Comment: No, only random chat with them. They use terraform also internally for the Google provider (their internal IT). I saw a [talk of Seth Vargo on this](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/closing-keynote-terraform-at-google) (Seth is a former HashiCorp employee and now Google Cloud Dev Advocate)